# Elasticsearch - Remove duplicate results when only one field matches

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to single out a field and remove all duplicate results when only one field is the same in an elasticsearch query? For example, all my results currently return a `url` field. Many of these results have a different `title` field, and so won't be filtered with most duplicate filtering methods. Is it possible to filter duplicates based on a single field? Currently using a bool query.

```
"_source": {
    "url": "/internal-revenue-manual/display_part?id=359"
}
```

```
$params_json = '

        {
            "body": {
                "sort" : [
                    {"timestamp" : 
                        {"order" : "desc", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"}
                    }
                ],
                "size" : 100,
                "query": {
                    "bool" : {
                        "must" : {
                            "match" : { "user_id" : '.$this->user_id.' }
                        },
                        "must_not": {
                            "match" : { "controller": "History" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ';
```

Here's a (hopefully) more clear example:

The current query is above. Here's a copy of what the query returns (simplified):

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "user_log",
        "_id": "[removed]",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2022-10-28T17:16:57.580Z",
          "product_id": "wl",
          "user_action": "page_navigation",
          "url": "/fakecontroller/fakeparam?id=123",
          "page": "Part 34 index",
          "module_title": "internal_revenue_manual",
          "message": "Page navigation to Internal Revenue Manual Part 34 index page",
          "host": {
            "name": "[removed]"
          },
          "controller": "InternalRevenueManual",
          "agent": {
            "type": "filebeat",
            "version": "7.9.2",
            "hostname": "[removed]"
          },
          "timestamp": "2022-10-28 17:16:54",

        },
        "sort": [
          "2022-10-28T17:16:57.580Z"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "user_log",
        "_id": "[removed]",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2021-12-29T17:19:57.580Z",
          "product_id": "wl",
          "user_action": "page_navigation",
          "url": "/fakecontroller/fakeparam?id=123",
          "page": "Part 34 index",
          "module_title": "internal_revenue_manual",
          "message": "Page navigation to Internal Revenue Manual Part 34 index page",
          "host": {
            "name": "[removed]"
          },
          "controller": "InternalRevenueManual",
          "agent": {
            "type": "filebeat",
            "version": "7.9.2",
            "hostname": "[removed]"
          },
          "timestamp": "2021-12-29 17:19:57",

        },
        "sort": [
          "2021-12-29T17:19:57.580Z"
        ]
      },
]
```

These two hits are identical aside from their date and time. Since they aren't completely identical, duplicate filtering hasn't worked. Is there a way to identify these are duplicates of each other, and filter them out? Ideally, based on the url value.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AmanMehta Just added a second example. I hope that clears things up. Just looking to remove duplicates from the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using [Collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-request-collapse.html) functionality.

Modify your elastic query like this -

```
{
  "body": {
    "sort" : [
       {"timestamp" : 
         {"order" : "desc", "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"}
       }
    ],
    "size" : 100,
    "query": {
       "bool" : {
          "must" : {
             "match" : { "user_id" : '.$this->user_id.' }
           },
           "must_not": {
             "match" : { "controller": "History" }
           }
       }
    },
    "collapse" : {
       "field: "url"
    }
  }
}
```

The result of this query will give you all matching documents with unique `url` value.

Comment: Hey @AmanMehta you are missing a double quote after "field".